# Find the relation?(if you are really smart)

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

SMOKE : TNPF

Question is simple just find how these two words are  related to each other

> Hint : 2✘13

Comment: @Greg please tell me how to hide hints

Comment: Use ">!" (if you click 'Edit' you can see how it's stylized).

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be TNPLF?

Comment: @zeethreepio yes it’s TNPF not TNPLF

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this right?

> Each letter of the second part is one letter further on in the alphabet.
>  However the fourth letter is missing.
>  The letter following K has been removed.
>  So my guess is that the "relative" is
>  
>  **Next of Kin once removed.**

Comment: Analysis the pattern formed when you place alphabets in 2*13 (row and columns)and count horizontally , upside down , then you get relation with numbers and you get water image then proceed

Comment: Still there is lot to do in this question

Comment: you were much near to finish the question so +1